# Not able to setup Arduino port

Tags: arduino-ide

I bought my Robotics kit yesterday. And, I am not able to set up my Arduino port.
I have tried every method I could find on the internet. I am attaching images of my device manager and error I am getting while trying to update my ports. Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: So the error says, that the best drivers are already installed. Can you choose the port COM3 or COM5 in your IDE? Or don't they show up?

Comment: @chrisl they don't show up. I am not able to select the option for ports.

Comment: add a sreenshot from the Tools menu

Comment: @Juraj Yes, added. Do let me know what might be the error.

Comment: @Juraj yes, I just did that. Followed https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=572898.0 for reference. Can you tell me how to proceed?

Comment: @Juraj I followed the instructions. Still getting the same error. Moreover, I have an Arduino Uno. So, it doesn't show me Duo Port programming under Ports(COM&LPT).

Comment: so your Uno is detected by Windows as Due?

Comment: @Juraj I am not quite sure of that. My model is Arduino UNO R3, and it detects the ports as COM3 and COM5.

Comment: uninstall the drivers you installed for the com port(s). do you have a link to description of the kit?

Comment: @Juraj Yes. https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B08CBLDNVL/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1